# Laravel Project Image Uploadings path error in CPanel

Tags: laravel, cpanel

i have uploaded my laravel project into the cpanel. but image upload function does not work correct that means, image path should be created on public_html/properties but those are created on project directory /public/properties.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you please show us image upload function?

Comment: Laravel does not have a `public_html` directory, and none of it's standard helpers or functionality (like [`public_path()`](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/helpers#method-public-path) etc use that.  If you are using `public_html/`, it is something custom in your upload code, so we would need to see that.